Balls in metric spaces
It is well known that the unit ball $B$ in a norm space must be absorbent, symmetrical with respect to the origin (that is, $B=-B$), convex and also does not contain a subspace of dimension $1$.
More than that, given a real vector space and a set $B$ of said space verifying the four properties stated above, it is possible to define a function (the Minkowski functional) that is a norm. The corresponding unit ball of such a norm is $\cap_{\lambda>1} \lambda B$. If the vector space is $\mathbb{R}^n$, the unit ball is equal to the closure of $B$ in the usual topology.
With this in mind, I want to know what can be said about balls in metric spaces that are also real vector spaces, when the metric does not necessary come from a norm. I know that metric balls need not to be convex. How about the other properties? Is there a version of the result stated in the second paragraph for metric spaces?

All four properties refer in some way to the vector space structure, so they make no sense in general metric spaces.

@Stefan You are right, I eas thinking about metric spaces that are also real vector spaces. I will include this. Thanks.

What kind of space do you have in mind for your generalization that is not a normed vector space?

@Adayah I was not thinking in any space in particular, but I know that even in $\mathbb{R}^2$ there are metric spaces that "makes sense" in real-life scenarios where the metric does not come from a norm, for instance the jungle-river metric.

At least, you would need that the induced topology is a vector space topology. If not, just consider any weird bijection $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, and redefine the usual metric via this bijection.
